# Installing mysql-server-5.6 fails on a strange error

Tags: mysql

still quite a newbie with Linux.

So, I had mysql 5.5 now tried to upgrade to 5.6 (made all the back ups no worries guys :D) tried all what was suggested on askubuntu also stackoverflow stills stuck with an error none I saw running into.

```
mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.6.22-1~) but 5.5.55-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
```

I honestly have no idea what's causing this, any help would be massively apperciated.

Comment: I believe your upgrade doesn't seem to want to take mysql-common with it. Your title should be `upgrading mysql fails`

Comment: So...? I gotta do it manually apart right?

Comment: What commands did you use to try to upgrade?

Comment: What did you try? `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install -f` ? `dpkg --configure -a` ? Please state the commands you already tried.

Comment: sudo apt-get update;
  sudo apt-get upgrade;
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6;

Answer (score 1):

Use these steps:

1. Backup your stuff **IMPORTANT**:

   ```
   sudo -i mysqldump --lock-all-tables --all-databases --events --ignore-table=mysql.event > dump.sql
   ```
2. Then use the steps below, **one command at a time**

   ```
   sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable    
   sudo invoke-rc.d apparmor restart    
   sudo replace log_slow_queries slow_query_log_file -- /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_slow_log.cnf    
   sudo bash -c 'echo "slow_query_log = 1" >> /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_slow_log.cnf'    
   sudo apt-get purge --assume-yes mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-client mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5    
   sudo apt-get update    
   export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive    
   sudo -E apt-get install --assume-yes mysql-server-5.6 mysql-client-5.6
   ```
3. Restore:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p < dump.sql
   ```

Source:

https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-upgrade-mysql-5.5-to-5.6-on-ubuntu-14.04.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/upgrade-mysql-5-5-to-5-6-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thank you for your help, sadly this didn't fix it.